# Survival Analysis--All variables failed the proportionality test. What next?

Tags: survival, sas, cox-model

I am building a  cox survival analysis  model with  a retailer's transaction data. Almost all the variables have failed the proportionality test. Can I continue with the Cox model? Should I build a LIFEREG model instead of the Cox model?

Comment: LIFEREG is not the name of a model.  Don't think of SAS as life.  Are the predictors such that they should have a constant effect over time?  If they have a diminishing effect over time you might go with an accelerated failure time model such as log-logistic or log-Gaussian.

Comment: Sorry about that.I meant Parametric models. I  created time dependent variables  ( model variables*log(time)) and these time dependent variables were significant. I even examined Schoenfeld Residuals to confirm and all the variables failed the test. I think I will try Parametric models. I was just concerned  that how can all the variables fail the test.

Comment: Make sure you used the time-dependent special likelihood; you can't use add product terms (with time) in the model.  I recommend fitting a couple of accelerated failure time models and plotting the Kaplan-Meier estimate of the distribution of the right-censored residuals to check agreement against the assumed distribution.